# TypeScript 5 enums

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript 5, [the behaviour of Enums changed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#all-enums-are-union-enums).

However, when I assign `string` values to the Color type instead of `int`s, the following code doesn't compile:

```
// Color is like a union of Red | Orange | Yellow | Green | Blue | Violet
enum Color {
    Red = 'Red', Orange = 'Orange', Yellow = 'Yellow', Green = 'Green', Blue = 'Blue'
}

// Each enum member has its own type that we can refer to!
type PrimaryColor = Color.Red | Color.Green | Color.Blue

function isPrimaryColor(c: Color): c is PrimaryColor {
    // Narrowing literal types can catch bugs.
    // TypeScript will error here because
    // we'll end up comparing 'Color.Red' to 'Color.Green'.
    // We meant to use ||, but accidentally wrote &&.
    return c === Color.Red || c === Color.Green || c === Color.Blue;
}

console.log(isPrimaryColor('Red')); // doesn't compile
console.log(isPrimaryColor(0)); // doesn't compile
console.log(isPrimaryColor('Red' as Color)); // compiles, works
console.log(isPrimaryColor(Color.Blue)); // compiles, works
```

Can anyone explain why? (The above code has been executed using TypeScript v5.1.0-dev.20230302)

Comment: Why do you relate this to TS 5? I see the same behaviour in the Playground for 3.7.5 or 4.2.3 or 4.9.5. These are just random versions I checked except the last one which is the default. [Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mpjYMw)

Comment: Because of the link I posted, but maybe I'm misinterpreting the change in 5.0.

Comment: The change in 5.0 is only noticeable on enums with [computed members](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members), and your example doesn't have any of those.  It's just a string enum with constant members.  Does that fully address your question, or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Ah, got it. I wasn't exactly sure what computed members were, but now I understand. So, in short, TypeScript enums are still far from ideal.

Comment: “So, in short, TypeScript enums are still far from ideal.” I don’t see  what you mean; what behavior is an issue for you and what would make it “ideal”?